# Why is the here map's custom icons not showing up in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, heremaps

I'm trying to show custom icons in here maps but it isn't showing up. I need help on this. As, it is also not throwing any error.
here is my recreation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zp8fy5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I know that i'm doing some silly mistake somewhere but can't point it where. BTW i also tried {icon: this.iconHMap } neither was it showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have defined some functions, but are not calling any of them. Since you are using elements from the DOM, you should probably use angular lifecycle hook `AfterViewInit` (https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) to call your initial setup-function, which seems to be `loadMap1(data, data1)`.

After that errors should pop up in the console, which can be handled.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it was not the full code i wrote(for which i apologise to not included it in the stackblitz) . As, i have declared it inside another API call inside in ngoninit.